# I was wondering why this code is not working?

Tags: vba

I know it is because of the "Or" but I was hoping someone could explain why it does not work.

```
If (Sheet.Name <> "Dep 1" Or "Test") Then
```

^

```
Sub DeleteSheet()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If (Sheet.Name <> "Dep 1" Or "Test") Then

        Sheet.Delete

     End If

 Next Sheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `<> Something or something else` is invalid, Find a VBA tutorial. You're looking for `(Sheet.Name <> "Something) or (Sheet.Name <> SomethingElse)`

Comment: Each side of the `Or` is required to be an `expression`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx

Comment: `If (Sheet.Name <> "Dep 1" Or Sheet.Name <>"Test") Then`

Comment: For future reference, *not working* is an absolutely meaningless problem description unless you explain specifically what *not working* means. If you get an error message, include the error message. If you get different behavior than you expected, explain what you expected and what you got instead. If you want help here, **be specific** about the problem you're having.

Comment: @ja72 - I think you meant `And` instead of `Or`.  That condition is always true.

Comment: @Comintern yes, 'And' is correct.

Comment: @SkysLastChance: Computers are programming use what's called Boolean Logic. There are good introductions online, including this one: http://www.i-programmer.info/babbages-bag/235-logic-logic-everything-is-logic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "Two-cents" to this post:

Try to use meaningful variable names, but **NOT** ones that are too close to Excel's saves words. `Dim Sheet` is ~ 85% similar to `Sheets`, which is a type of `Object`, I've seen so many posts here that people get `cell` with `Cells` mixed-up and get a run-time error.

I've switched your `If` with `Select Case .Name`, this way, if in the future you have add more `Worksheets` or want to perform other actions on other `Worksheets`, it will be easier to modify the code.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        Select Case .Name
            Case "Dep 1", "Test"
                ' do nothing for now
            Case Else
                .Delete
        End Select
    End With
Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' <-- restore setting

End Sub
```